# UnavailableShardsException on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch on my dedicated server (not amazon). Recently it's giving me error like:

> UnavailableShardsException[[tribune][4] Primary shard is not active or
>   isn't assigned is a known node. Timeout: [1m], request: delete
>   {[tribune][news][90755]}]

when ever I'm making **/_cat/shards?v** the result is:

```
index   shard prirep state        docs  store ip            node          
tribune 4     p      UNASSIGNED                                           
tribune 4     r      UNASSIGNED                                           
tribune 0     p      STARTED      5971   34mb ***.**.***.** Benny Beckley 
tribune 0     r      UNASSIGNED                                           
tribune 3     p      STARTED      5875 33.9mb ***.**.***.** Benny Beckley 
tribune 3     r      UNASSIGNED                                           
tribune 1     p      INITIALIZING             ***.**.***.** Benny Beckley 
tribune 1     r      UNASSIGNED                                           
tribune 2     p      STARTED      5875 33.6mb ***.**.***.** Benny Beckley 
tribune 2     r      UNASSIGNED
```

Comment: It looks like the shard 4 and it's replica are really not assigned. Did you try restarting your cluster?

Comment: Trying now. I will let you know what happens.

Comment: I also advice you to use site-plugins to have a better visualization of your cluster.

Comment: Which plugin should I install?

Comment: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/03/elasticsearch-monitoring-and-management-plugins/

Comment: I actually use head, hq, kopf and marvel (official monitoring plugin). Each of them present a different set of features from the other. Head is really basic so it should be a good start!